# Reading Georgian Characters Unity text editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i try to write Georgian characters in unity (example: გამარჯობა) in text field only appear question marks. I use Unity 5.6 on Windows 8.

I think it is a problem of the windows font which uses Unity. Can I change default font for Unity UI?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzXU4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I change default font for Unity UI?

[image]

You can also do this from script:

```
public Font yourFont;
GetComponent<Text>().font = yourFont;
```

or from the Resources folder:

```
GetComponent<Text>().font = (Font)Resources.Load("Yourfont");
```

---

Just download a Georgian font, import it into Unity and use one of the methods above to apply it to the `Text` component.